# getting events/feeds in google calendar to show as a list

Tags: html, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a list of all events in my calendar and show it in my project website. any idea on how to get/retrieve the events/feeds  in my goggle calendar and show it as a list any tutorial on the matter is much appreciated. i been searching but i cant find any as far as i have researched all i see is [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en&ref_topic=1672470) tutorial which i don't not understand at all.

all i want is to display the events/feeds  of my calendar below the calendar itself so people doest have to look it up in the calendar
i want something like [this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/upcoming-events/) but not in word press i want it on my own html

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for it myself. Followed the goodle documentation for 2 days now and still don't get it.